# CIDR block is malformed. What is wrong with this CLI command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to set up an IP address for a security group with CLI. But for some reason AWS throws an error. And the value is just absolutely correct because I'm setting the same value as set there at the time of command execution. What is wrong? Why is this error?

```
$ aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr 'xx.xx.xxx.xx/32' --group-id sg-xxxxxxxx

An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress operation: CIDR block xx.xx.xxx.xx\32 is malformed
```

Comment: do you have a valid IP ? not ending by `.0` or `.255` ?

Comment: I think it might be a bug in aws API, it happens to me sometimes, rerunning the command and it works later.

Comment: IPs ending in .0 or .255 can be valid

Answer (score 2):

Your command **worked perfectly well for me** (substituting an IP address and a security group).

You might want to try it without the **single-quotes**.

Also, the error with a **backslash** (`CIDR block xx.xx.xxx.xx\32 is malformed`) is a little concerning, as if it has converted your input. I receive exactly the same error if I use a backslash (`\`) instead of a forward slash (`/`).

Comment: I use forward slash, but git bash makes it backward every time. None of the variant works: `\/`, `//`, `///`, `\\/`, `\\//`. Every time backslash is returned

Comment: The single quotes are removed by the shell; the command won't see them. They have no effect here.